# React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I used `useEffect` in my component in order to execute an async function.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    scoreRequest(answers);
  }, [answers]);
```

Then I get this warning:

```
React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'scoreRequest'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

I used the `useCallback` to avoid this warning:

```
const getScore = useCallback(() => {
  scoreRequest(answers);
  }, [answers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    scoreRequest(answers);
  }, [answers]);
```

But still got the same error. However, I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook) and it's mentioned in the answer either to declare the function into the useEffect  or I could disable the rule.
The function `scoreRequest()` declared in another file and I don't want to mix it with my component.

```
export const scoreRequest = (answers: IAnswer[]): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(startScoreRequest());
    getScoreApi(answers).then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      const { data } = response;
      const answer = {
        scoreLabel: data.message,
        userScore: data.result.userScore,
        totalScore: data.result.totalScore,
        emoji: data.result.emoji,
        scoreLabelColor: data.result.scoreLabelColor
      };
      dispatch(successScore(answer));
    }, (error: AxiosError) => {
      let errorMessage = "Internal Server Error";
      if (error.response) {
        errorMessage = error.response.data.error;
      }
      dispatch(failScore(errorMessage));
      dispatch(errorAlert(errorMessage));
    });
  };
};
```

Is it any solution to fix this warning?

Comment: Are you importing this function or receiving it as `prop`?

Comment: @Dupocas receiving as prop

Comment: You could simply add `scoreRequest` to dependency array if you are sure that it is only created once or you could disable the eslint rule

Comment: Unless he memoize `scoreRequest` a new instance gets created every render always triggering the effect .

Comment: @Dupocas That depends on whether you create the function inside of the functional component or outside of it

Comment: that's why I suggested to import the action creator directly from the component instead of receiving it as a prop